# Is there a way to download specific Unity Addressables remote group?

Tags: unity-game-engine, addressables

I'm using Addressables remote groups in my game. Each group is packed in separate asset bundle. I'd like to download some remote groups, that I specify in my config file on application start. But, as I understand `Addressables.DownloadDependenciesAsync(...)` works only with certain assets. It determines which bundles should be downloaded to make specified asset is loaded well, and download them.

But could I somehow specify group name or something to download certain asset bundle?

Answer (score 0):

Not group specific, but we use different catalogs and use ***LoadContentCatalogAsync*** like this to load a particular remote catalog:

```
    private async void Awake()
    {
        AsyncOperationHandle<IResourceLocator> loadContentCatalogAsync = Addressables.LoadContentCatalogAsync(GetCurrentPlatformURL(), true);
        await loadContentCatalogAsync.Task;

        List<Task> loadingTasks = new(_preloadedAssetNames.Count);

        foreach (string assetName in _preloadedAssetNames)
        {
            var downloadTask = Addressables.DownloadDependenciesAsync(assetName, true);
            loadingTasks.Add(downloadTask.Task);
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(loadingTasks);
        _initialized = true;
    }
```